# Win2k3 Media Services - archiving video and indexing for Silverlight

Tags: windows-server-2003, video-streaming, windows

I’m stuck with a WME9-based live video streaming client, which streams to a Win2k3 SP1 Windows Media Server.  The server archives the file for on-demand playback after the live broadcast is over.

I’ve recently switched from using a WMP plugin for playback to a Silverlight player.  The Silverlight player works well, and simplifies supporting more diverse viewers, but in the switch we’ve lost the ability to seek in the archived videos.

The same file seeks just fine under WMP, so I’m wondering if there’s something we need to do at the server side to ensure that WMS indexes the file differently for Silverlight playback.

I’ve set up an example at http://www.versestudios.com/streaming/ – any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The esteemed Tim Heuer ( http://timheuer.com/blog/ ) provided the answer as to "why" it's happening via email (Thanks Tim!):

Looks like you are using server-side playlist which Silverlight doesn't support:

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645037(VS.95).aspx#Integrate

So now I'll just find a way around that, I guess!